# Where does the first carry-in go on a adder/subtractor circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, adder, alu

I am building a 4-bit adder/subtractor circuit using only logic gates on a breadboard. The following IC chips are being used:
XOR- 7486, AND - 7408, OR - 7432.

I have the full adders working fine. However, I can't seem to get my subtractor working, using an XOR gate - 7486. I understand the math, 2s complement, truth table, and concepts. I attached a schematic.

Problem: I don't understand where to connect the first carry-in. Since there is no carry-in on the first adder, I tied it to ground. That makes the adder work.

However, in order for the subtractor to work, I am confused about where to connect the first carry-in. The schematic shows it to be connected to both the mode switch and the first B input for the first full adder. I did that. It just makes the circuit light up random values. Even when all the inputs are low. I have the first input of B (LSB, B0) connected to the XOR, along with the first carry-in. The output is connected to the B input of the full adder.

I get the feeling that I am making this more difficult than it should be. If I can get the first carry-in connected correctly, I believe I will be fine from there.

[image: adder/subtractor]

As soon as I flip on subtractor (¬ADD/SUB) to high, the value 4 comes on, without any inputs (A = 0, B = 0).
When A = 0 and B = 1, the value is 3.
When A = 1 and B = 1, the value is 4.
When A = 3 and B = 1, the value is 6.
When A = 2 and B = 3, the value is 3.
Also, the adders were working fine until I hooked up the subtractor. The adders are not giving correct values either.
It has to be my first carry-in is wrong.
However, I have it connected to the mode and the carry-in, as well as the XOR.

Comment: The schematics looks fine. Carry-in is set to one when subtracting using two's complement : A - B = (A + /B + 1)

Comment: Yes. However, when I set the carry-in to one, it immediately displays random outputs, even when the inputs are 0. Does the first carry-in need to be disconnected from the adder?

Comment: Please specify some test cases (A, B and S) for what you are calling "random values".

Comment: Ad soon as I flip on subtractor to high, the value 4 comes on, without any inputs ( A = 0, B = 0).

Comment: When A = 0 and B = 1, it gives the value 3.  A = 1 and B = 1, the value is 4.  When A = 3 and B = 1, the value is 6. When A = 2 and B = 3, the output is 3.

Comment: Also, the adders were working fine until I hooked u the subtractor. The adders are not giving correct values either. It has to be my first carry-in is wrong. However, I have it connected to the mode and the carry-in, as well as the XOR .

Comment: @MichaelPaxinos [This is one way to do what you want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Ay8.png) Is what you have close to it? If you need some explanation I can write it up. But it sounds as though you are already quite close. So I didn't bother writing.

Comment: • How do you arrive at the digits you use for output & input? When SUB is asserted and A and B are equal, the output is 4. With B one higher than A, it is 3, a 2 higher yields 6: consistently 4 too high so far.

Comment: @MichaelPaxinos [Here's a complete add/sub ALU with status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd8yI.png). There are two gates that need to be implemented in 7400 that I didn't include. But this is pretty much the whole deal.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic is correct: with SUB set to 1 the 4 XOR gates invert all the bits in B and add one (carry in), thus computing the two's complement.

Besides any a errors at the breadboard connections, or damaged ICs, what may explain the "random values" is a wrong conversion for negative values, which may actually be correct.

These are the expected values for the test cases you provided (with SUB = 1):

```
A   B  =  S   Cout
0   0  =  0   1
0   1  =  F   0
1   1  =  0   1
3   1  =  2   1
2   3  =  F   0
```

I'd suggest that you check the intermediate values with a multimeter or a "LED probe" to find the error.

Comment: Thank you @devnull. I never got F. I did notice that the voltage dropped by .5V when I switched from the adder to SUB. I must be grounding something that shouldn't be grounded.

Comment: @MichaelPaxinos if the schematic looks right, the error may be in the breadboard. I'd not short an input to a power rail, but use a 100 Ω resistor. I've suggested to consolidate several comments into the question body, information about the voltage drop should go there too, and possibly an image of the breadboard.